# Proof of Arnold-Liouville's Thm: movement in angular coordinates conditionally periodic

Tags: mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

I'm reading Arnold's book *Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics* and got stuck on the proof of Liouville's theorem on integrable systems. The proof finishes with Problem 11: Show that the motion on the invariant torus $M_f$ is conditionally periodic.

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start. Can anyone help me out?

*Edit*: I think the reasoning is somewhat as follows: The action of the flow of $H$ is linear on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the $t$-coordinates (but I don't understand yet why). Then we divide out the lattice $\Gamma$ to get a linear action on the torus $T^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ in the $\varphi$-coordinates. Now there should be a result that any linear action on a torus is conditionally periodic.

Comment: Could you tell me at which page of the book (and chapter) I can find this problem ? (I have the Second Edition)

Comment: It is the very last page of section 49: Integrable systems, chapter 10: Introduction to pertubation theory. I have the second edition as well and it is on the bottom of page 278.

Answer (score 0):

By flowing along the Hamiltonian vector fields corresponding to the Poisson commuting functions $f:= (f_1 = H, f_2,\ldots, f_n)$ and restricting attention to a level set $M_f$, we obtain an action of $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\times M_f \to M_f$. Let's fix some point $x_0 \in M_f$ and consider the orbit map $\Phi_{x_0}:\mathbb{R}^n \to M_f$ defined by $\Phi_{x_0}(v) = \Phi(v,x_0)$. The stabilizer of this map is a rank $n$ subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that the flow $\psi^H_t$ corresponding to the Hamiltonian $H$ is given by $\psi^H_t(x)\mapsto \Phi(te_1,x)$.

Now let $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ be a basis for the free abelian group $\Gamma$, and let $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the invertible matrix defined by $A e_i = v_i$. The map $\Phi_{x_0}\circ A$ has stabilizer $\mathbb{Z}^n\leq \mathbb{R}^n$ and descends through the quotient to a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{T}^n = \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n \to M_f$ which defines the circle-valued coordinates $\varphi:=(\varphi^1,\ldots,\varphi^n)$. Since the $\Phi_{x_0}$ is surjective, for any $x \in M_f$ there exists $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Phi_{x_0}(w) =x$. Using this fact and the previous paragraph, we obtain

$$\psi_t^H(x) = \Phi(te_1,x) = \Phi(te_1,\Phi(w,x_0)) = \Phi_{x_0}(te_1 + w) =\Phi_{x}(AA^{-1}(te_1+w)) = [\Phi_{x}\circ A]( tA^{-1}e_1 + A^{-1}w) = [\Phi_{x}\circ A]( \omega t + A^{-1}w),$$

where the vector $\omega:=A^{-1}e_1$. Therefore, $$\dot{\varphi} = \omega$$

as desired.